How can I completely remove padding from PYQT6 widgets?
I'm creating a sign-in box for a GUI app. The sign-in box contains three QLabels, two QLineEdits and a QPushButoon. I have all of these widgets inside a QFrame widget with a QVBoxLayout. I want the widgets to be as close ass possible, but I haven't been able to find a way to do that. I've playing around with the following code to try and find a solution. Basically, I want the green, blue and purple labels to be immediately below each other like so:

green
blue
purple


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        boxLayout = QVBoxLayout()
  
        masterframe = Color('black')
        
        color1 = QLabel('green')
        color1.setStyleSheet("""padding: 0px; background-color: green; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px""") 
        color2 = QLabel('blue')
        color2.setStyleSheet("""padding: 0px; background-color: blue; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px""")
        color3 = QLabel('purple')
        color3.setStyleSheet("""padding: 0px; background-color: purple; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px""")
        

        boxLayout.addWidget(color1)
        boxLayout.addWidget(color2)
        boxLayout.addWidget(color3)

        
        masterframe.setLayout(boxLayout)
        masterframe.setFixedSize(100,500)
        layout.addWidget(masterframe)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()

The image below illustrates my problem, I want the padding of each box to be 0 so that the labels can be immediately below each other:

I've tried using the .move() function but the widgets won't move since the master Frame has a fixed size. I've tried applying CSS style sheets with 0 padding and 0 margin but the widgets still won't align as I want them.

What do you get if you set both padding and margin to 0?

It could be what you're seeing might be the elements' margins, not padding, or maybe the layout is applying some gap style between items in the layout.

nothing changed when adding a margin to 0px

What happens if you set the spacing property of the QVBoxLayout to 0?

@mkrieger1 with boxLayout.setSpacing(0), the gap between each QLabel box disappears, but the padding inside the QLabel widget remains unchanged.


layout.setAlignment(Qt.Alignment.AlignTop) (or, alternatively, layout.addStretch() after adding everything) to push everything on top; 2. layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) to remove any margin of the layout manager; 3. layout.setSpacing(0) to remove any further spacing between items managed by the layout. Remember that the purpose of layout managers is to optimize the usage of available space (or eventually require more), while the main purpose of QSS is to manage the appearance within the geometry allocated by any parent or layout manager.


@musicamante much appreciated, it's working as expected now.

@musicamante with setContentsMargin I was also able to create space between the QLabels. For example: color2.setContentsMargins(0,20,0,0) creates 20 pixels of space between green and blue. However, I'm only able to create this spacing with QLabels. If I add a QPushButton or QLineEdit setContentsMargins does not achieve the desired result. Any workarounds for this?

setContentsMargins() is mostly intended for container widgets. If you want to add custom spacing, use the appropriate layout functions (such as addSpacing() for box layouts).

gotcha thank you very much. My last question is, if I want to add spacing from the left margin I should still use button.QPushButton(20,0,0,0) right? The only issue is that I find that for some QWidgets is difficult to control their position within their space.
